Using TypeScript Record to define partial list of Keys
I am trying to use a Record to map the keys of one object to a different object. I essentially want to take the CountryCode options defined by Google's libphonenumber and map them to my own formatting objects. This works:
const countryOptions: Record<CountryCode, CountryFormat> = {
  'US': {
    //... my CountryFormat object
  },
  //...
}

However, this requires me to define every key in CountryCode, like 240 countries. I am not enabling all of these countries so I would rather not define anything for them. Is it possible to define this record type in a way that is only for partial keys of CountryCode?

Is there some reason you can't use Partial<Record<CountryCode, CountryFormat>>?

Use the Partial built-in utility type:
const countryOptions: Partial<Record<CountryCode, CountryFormat>> = {
  'US': {
    //... my CountryFormat object
  },
  //...
}

This makes all properties optional.

If you are not bound to use a Record you can try to use a Map where the keys are the country codes.
countryOptions: new Map<string, CountryFormat>([
    ["US", {
        //... my CountryFormat object
    }],
    ["UK", {
        //... my CountryFormat object
    }],
    //...
]);


Map<CountryCode, CountryFormat> would make a lot more sense over Map<string, CountryFormat>

Using a Map like this, particularly when still using the CountryCode type as the key (requirement for my use case), does work. But it loses the direct use of the CountryCode as an accessor, and so I think the other answer is preferable.
